# Using React component from js source maps

Tags: reactjs

Long story short, I'm trying to learn React to use in one of my projects. I'm now trying to use a react component (https://github.com/mozilla-services/react-jsonschema-form) but I don't understand how to use it with the CDN version. So there is a [js file](https://npmcdn.com/react-jsonschema-form/dist/react-jsonschema-form.js)  and also a [source map](https://npmcdn.com/react-jsonschema-form/dist/react-jsonschema-form.js.map)

The component looks pretty straight forward to use:

```
const schema = {
  title: "Todo",
  type: "object",
  required: ["title"],
  properties: {
    title: {type: "string", title: "Title", default: "A new task"},
    done: {type: "boolean", title: "Done?", default: false}
  }
};

const formData = {
  title: "First task",
  done: true
};

const log = (type) => console.log.bind(console, type);

render((
  <Form schema={schema}
        formData={formData}
        onChange={log("changed")}
        onSubmit={log("submitted")}
        onError={log("errors")} />
), document.getElementById("app"));
```

If I correctly understood, using the CDN approach, I should be able to just include the js(and also react/react-dom) and it should work, right? Only I get an error:

```
embedded:18 Uncaught ReferenceError: Form is not defined
```

When I look in the js file, I don't see the Form component specified, while I do see it in the map:

```
class Form extends Component
```

So how exactly should this be used? As I feel I'm missing something here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Form is only available in the examples after importing and aliasing the `JSONSchemaForm` module which is why it doesn't show up in the minified version.

```
import Form from "react-jsonschema-form";
```

However, the compiled ES module is added to the global namespace as `JSONSchemaForm` in the CDN version and you can manually access its default export property.

```
const Form = JSONSchemaForm.default;
```

Then use it as a React component.

```
ReactDOM.render((
  <Form schema={schema}
    formData={formData}
    onChange={log("changed")}
    onSubmit={log("submitted")}
    onError={log("errors")} />
  ),
  document.getElementById("app")
);
```

Comment: You, sir, deserve a large pint of beer. Thanks a lot! Works well now.

Comment: In which file I have to add this ? ```const Form = JSONSchemaForm.default;```

Comment: @SaketKumar If you're using it from a CDN, then you need that in every file that you want to render a `<Form />` component

Comment: I'm getting this error ```'JSONSchemaForm' is not defined.``` when adding     ```const form = JSONSchemaForm.default```

Comment: How are you adding `JSONSchemaForm` to your project?