# How to display Form component in React app from react-jsonschema-form library? 'JSONSchemaForm' is not defined no-undef

Tags: reactjs, webpack, undefined-reference, react-jsonschema-forms

I'm learning React. I'm trying to add a react FORM component from https://github.com/rjsf-team/react-jsonschema-form?fbclid=IwAR0HdGosg659-F0hdFp-milh29G_6UX5_qbti6lZBmo7OYKIxgThD5f1Ff8 to my dummy application. I used react json schema form documentation https://react-jsonschema-form.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#installation .

I have red [Using React component from js source maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36302120/using-react-component-from-js-source-maps)  and [react-jsonschema-form How to use it via cdn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40312418/react-jsonschema-form-how-to-use-it-via-cdn) which might be addressing similar problem. However, I am still struggling a lot.

I did:

1. `npx create-react-app my-app`
2. `cd my-app`, `npm install`
   My react version is
   "react": "^16.13.1",
   "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
   "react-scripts": "3.4.1"
3. `npm install @rjsf/core --save`

My dummy App.js component:

```
import React from 'react';
import Form from "@rjsf/core";

function App() {

  const Form = JSONSchemaForm.default;
const schema = {
  type: "string"
};

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Form schema={schema} />
      
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I hit npm start and get error:

```
./src/App.js
  Line 6:16:  'JSONSchemaForm' is not defined  no-undef
```

From what I understand, webpack can't find JSONSchemaForm module (?)
I tried adding cdn file from the documentation to index.html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@rjsf/core/dist/react-jsonschema-form.js"></script>
    
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
```

It didn't help. Documentation says I should add a source map. However, I am not familiar with source maps. I red definition on mozilla MDN, but I don't know how to implement it.  I am also not familiar with manually setting webpack configurations, nor require.js mentioned in this solution [react-jsonschema-form How to use it via cdn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40312418/react-jsonschema-form-how-to-use-it-via-cdn)  .

Question is - how likely is it that adding source map would solve the problem? Do in need to learn webpack?  Do you see other reasons why I can't display Form component?

If adding source map would likely solve the problem, what webpack properties are essential to know in this case?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit new to React as well, but here are my two cents on this -- when you already have imported `Form` using  `import Form from "@rjsf/core";`, I don't think you need `const Form = JSONSchemaForm.default;` again. Just remove the `const Form = JSONSchemaForm.default;` line and try again.